# Fun problems with binary operations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

Does anyone know of a book / internet resource containing lots of problems relating to properties of binary operations?

An example of the sort of problem I'm looking for is:

Let * be a binary operation on a set $A$ such that 
$$\text{for all } x, y \in A, \, x*(y*x)=y.$$
Prove that 
$$\text{for all } x, y \in A, \, (x*y)*x=y.$$

Comment: There's a chapter on Galois connections between operators and relations in Denecke & Wismath's [*Universal Algebra and Applications*](http://www.amazon.com/Universal-Algebra-Applications-Theoretical-Computer/dp/1584882549), 2002, though not necessarily exercises, or limited to binary ops.

Comment: The problems at http://people.emich.edu/phoward/w02/411w2h1.pdf may be below the level you want, but have a look.

Comment: https://books.google.it/books?id=MQbvAAAAMAAJ&q=Pflugfelder&dq=Pflugfelder&hl=it&sa=X&ei=iSPEVI-gHo75apiogAg&redir_esc=y This book contains a lot of proofs of implications between properties of (mainly non associative) binary operations.